# Gradle Liquibase Integration

Tags: gradle, liquibase

I am trying to integrate Liquibase in my project using Gradle.
For that I made below changes to `build.gradle` but it gives me error as follows:

[image]

Below is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { 
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }
}

allprojects {'
    apply plugin: 'liquibase'
}

dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.1'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.0.1'
    liquibaseRuntime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
  }

liquibase {
    activities {
        doFirst {
            if (!project.hasProperty('runList')) {
                project.ext.runList = "main,test"
            }
        }
        main {
            defaultsFile "$projectDir/sql-migration/mysql/app_mysql.properties"
            logFile "$projectDir/sql-migration/mysql/logs/liquibase-" + new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss")+".log"
        }
        test {
            defaultsFile "$projectDir/sql-migration/mysql/app_test_mysql.properties"
            logFile "$projectDir/sql-migration/logs/liquibase-test-" + new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss")+".log"
        }
    }
    // To execute liquibase on single environment, gradlew app:update -PrunList=test
    runList = project.ext.runList
}
```

I am not able to get why it is not able to find out 'liquibaseRuntime' repositories.
Any help in this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a **changelog file**, make sure that the changelog file is properly referenced from build.gradle.

Also I would suggest defining the **liquibase.url**, username and password.

Refer to this post for detailed implementation:

https://dzone.com/articles/managing-your-database-with-liquibase-and-gradle

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> Cannot resolve external dependency [...] because no repositories are defined

indicates that you're missing a `repositories` block. You have one in your `buildscript`, but you probably need to move it to the top-level, as shown [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html).